# Why can't PyCharm show PyTorch Module object attributes in debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pytorch

I define a sub-class of PyTorch's `Module` in PyCharm and create an instance `a`:

```
from torch.nn import Module

class AModule(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = 10

    def __repr__(self):
        return "AModule"

a = AModule()
```

If I run the debugger and examine `a`, I can't see its attributes:

[image]

I checked and `Module` is written in Python (as opposed to being implemented in C), so why is that?

Comment: Part of this seems to be a problem with pytorch itself, somehow - I tried running the code through `pdb` and examining `dir(a)`, which threw an error `*** torch.nn.modules.module.ModuleAttributeError: 'AModule' object has no attribute '_parameters'`. Various other questions I found by googling that error message seem to think that the way you're invoking `Module` could be to blame - what does your `import` statement look like, and can you edit that into your question?

Comment: That said, this seems like it might also expose a bug with PyCharm and the engine it's using for debug (it should probably handle a situation like this more gracefully than it seems to be doing). If no one posts a conclusive answer in a reasonable timeframe you might consider [submitting a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues).

Comment: Thanks, you're right that I am using Module incorrectly. I should have invoked Module's __init__ in AModule's init. Feel free to submit an answer to get that credit; otherwise I will do it tomorrow. And yes, I agree PyCharm could handle it more gracefully.

Comment: Created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by not having properly initialized `Module` with a `super` call in the first like of `__init__`:

```
super(AModule, self).__init__()
```

However, PyCharm could have shown more useful information, so I created [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44277).